# HTML border differences in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, browser

I'm having some trouble identifying the problem with my html code.  I've created a table and it is like this on Internet Explorer (which is the result I'm looking for):

[image: IE]

But it comes up like this on Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

...and I don't know how to fix this.  Please help, thanks.

Comment: Attachments are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `border-collapse: collapse;` to your table's styles. [Documentation Here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp).

If that doesn't fix it: While the images help, what would help even more is the HTML/CSS that you are using to get the results. That way we can see what the problem may be better.

Comment: in order to get this towork cross-browser you also need to add cellspacing = "0" to the table element in your html I think

Comment: What browser needs that? IE6?